# How to explode a Dictionary List as headers in a format-table

Tags: powershell, dictionary, formatting

**UPDATED to include listing blank/empty properties from objects**

Sorry for the title, not sure how to label this question. I want to express a list of Dictionary objects with Key as Header/Property and Value as the header's/property's value.

For example take the following PoSH code

```
$obj1 = new-object object | select Data; $obj1.Data = @{"header1"="Value1";"header2"="Value2";}
$obj2 = new-object object | select Data; $obj2.Data = @{"header1"="ValueA";"header2"="ValueB";}
$obj3 = new-object object | select Data; $obj3.Data = @{"header1"="Value1";"header3"="ValueC";}

$tmp = @($obj1,$obj2,$obj3)
```

`$tmp` then looks like the following:

```
Data                       
----                        
{header2, header1}
{header2, header1}
{header3, header1}
```

`$tmp | select -Expand Data` gets the following useful information

```
Name                           Value   
----                           -----       
header2                        Value2
header1                        Value1
header2                        ValueB
header1                        ValueA
header3                        ValueC
header1                        Value1
```

Anyway I can pivot the data and turn the Names into Properties (or headers) and express them with values i.e.

```
header1                        header2               header3
----                           -----                 -----
Value1                         ValueB
ValueA                         Value2
Value1                                               ValueC
```

**Note:** I've been able to do this by writing a function that takes each object in my Dictionary list, creates a new object and adds the Properties via Add-Member, but it's an expensive and slow process when you have thousands of entries and thousands of Dictionary Keys

Comment: That is the only way that I am aware of. If it is expensive, then perhaps a dictionary is not the right data storage structure. Personally I would use an array of custom objects.

Comment: Right, but the data i'm working with is returned as such. For example [System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.propertycollection.aspx)

Comment: You get a collection of those objects?

Comment: Right, I'll have an array or list of Directory Objects. For instance, a AD query that returns objects; those objects have a property "Attributes" which contains a list of attributes represented in a Dictionary List.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Powershell v2 new-object has a `property` parameter which lets you enter a hash table in which the keys are the names of properties and the values are property value.

```
$tmp | select -expand data | %{new-object psobject -property $_}
```

gives:

```
header2                                                     header1
-------                                                     -------
Value2                                                      Value1
ValueB                                                      ValueA
```

Comment: Very nice! I ended up adding to your example to get me what I needed
`$tmp | select -ExpandProperty Data | % {new-object psobject -Property $_ } | select ($tmp | select -ExpandProperty data | % { $_.Keys } | sort -Unique) | ft`
Not sure how efficient it is, but will get me all the "header" values even for objects that are missing them. That way I can pipe the results to Export-CSV and generate a report

Answer (score 1):

What about this :

```
$tmp | % {"header1,header2"}{$_.data.header1+","+$_.data.header2} | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

it gives :

```
header1                                                                    header2
-------                                                                    -------
Value1                                                                     Value2
ValueA                                                                     ValueB
```

Comment: How would I be able to achieve this dynamically (not knowing the number of headers? Or looping through a list?)